# How to Validate Username and Password using Dataset

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to make a login page in APS.NET C# however, I don't know how to validate the username and password using a Dataset.

Below is the code that I have written for the Login Button:

```
if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
   conn.Open();



    SqlDataAdapter myadp3 = new SqlDataAdapter("select * FROM Login WHERE username='" + DropUser.SelectedItem.Text+ "' and pass='" + TextBox1.Text+"'", conn);

    DataSet DSS = new DataSet();
    adp.Fill(DSS);
```

How can I check login credentials using Dataset in If condition?

Comment: My password of `' DROP TABLE Login; --` doesn't work with your program. Also it seems to crash after I try to log in once.

Comment: It's OK, try the password `' OR 1=1; --`. Works every time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed) 
conn.Open();
SqlDataAdapter myadp3 = new SqlDataAdapter("select * FROM Login WHERE username='" + DropUser.SelectedItem.Text+ "' and pass='" + TextBox1.Text+"'", conn);      

DataSet DSS = new DataSet();
adp.Fill(DSS);

if (DSS != null && DSS.Tables.Count > 0 && DSS.Tables[0].Rows.Count>0)
{
    //right your logic here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can overcome the problem.

But I recommend you to login using stored procedure

Basic sample: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0c1bb2/login-page-in-Asp-Net-C-Sharp-web-application-using-stored-proce/

**CODE:**

```
SqlDataAdapter myadp3 = new SqlDataAdapter("select * FROM Login WHERE username='" + DropUser.SelectedItem.Text+ "' and pass='" + TextBox1.Text+"'", conn);
DataSet DSS = new DataSet();
adp.Fill(DSS);
if(DSS.Tables.Count>0){
    if(DSS.Tables[0].Rows.Count>0){
        return true; // login success
    }
}
```